# Changing browser height not detected by .resize function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the .resize function to trigger some adjustments. When I decrease/increase the browser width size it works ok, but when I decrease/increase the browser height nothing happens. Any idea why changing the browser height does not get detected by the .resize function? (same behavior in Chrome and IE9)

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Yes: $(window).resize(function(){
  //stuff
});

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want:

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // hide the scroll bars
$(window).resize(function(){
  var newwidth = $(window).width();
  var newheight = $(window).height();      
  $("#elementId").height(newheight).width(newwidth);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/jsbrown/pen/808f04b7d61b7cbfccc23e22794742c4/)

Comment: Thanks. But the problem I am having is that when I change the browser height manually (not by code) then it doesn't even all the first line of the .resize function.. only if I manually adjust the width of the browser (I should have added "manually" to my original question. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The `resize` function is being triggered just fine in the code above. Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Let me try to explain myself better... just like you I have the $(window).resize(function(){....}); , but with my browser window not maximized, if I use the "arrows" to re-size the height of the "window", then the code in the .resize function doesn't get triggered. It does "execute" the code in the .resize function if I use the arrows to re-size the width of the "window".

Comment: James.. I just tried your demo in Chrome. Without the browser window maximized (so floating in the desktop), if you use the "vertical" or "horizontal" arrows to resize the "window", you can see that sometimes scroll bars appear and sometimes they don't... suggesting that the .resize function is not doing the same reading every time... do you get this behavior?

Comment: Add `document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';` to the top of your js. This should fixed the problem. See the updated demo.

Comment: Thanks for you help. My point is that the browser is reading the event differently at different times. For some reason. with the browser window not maximized and using the arrows to manually increase or decrease the "window" height, my .resize function does not get triggered (if I put a stop point in it it doesn't even execute the first line). It only executes the code in the .resize function if I increase/decrease the window's width. So my problem is not what happens when the .resize function is called... problem is that when manually changing height it doesn't even get triggered... thx again

Comment: That's weird... could you please post the code you are using to do this so I can mess around with it?